# Extracting a certain section of a string

Tags: php

How do I get the value of tracking_id from a string similar to the string below:

```
action_type=PAY&transaction_type=Adaptive+Payment+PAY&tracking_id=bovxedxgM&status=COMPLETED&
```

That is just a snipped of a much longer string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str):

```
parse_str('your-string-here', $data);
echo $data['tracking_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arguments = array();
parse_str('action_type=PAY&transaction_type=Adaptive+Payment+PAY&tracking_id=bovxedxgM&status=COMPLETED', $arguments);
$tracking_id = $arguments['tracking_id'];
```

http://php.net/parse-str